# Google maps geocoder returns Not found

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to use the geocoder to get co-ordinates for the following address:

```
1945 Barton Street, Hamilton, ON, L8H2Y7
```

Searching the address on google maps itself finds the address: http://g.co/maps/5axb5.
Using the geocode url also returns fine. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1945+BARTON+STREET,+HAMILTON,+ON,+L8H2Y7&sensor=false

However, when I use the api (my code below), it returns not found.

[image]

Code: (this works fine for several other addresses I'm searching)

```
if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': fullAddress }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocoding failed: " + status + "  " + fullAddress);
        }
    });
}
```

The "actual" address is "1945 Barton Street **East**, Hamilton, ON L8H2Y7, Canada", but maps and the direct url still find the place fine, only the geocoder doesn't.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

EDIT: 
I figured it out. It was a different address that it legitimately couldn't find (not on google maps or using the geocoder), but because the request was being done asynchronously by the time the geocoder realized it couldn't find the address, the loop had already changed the address value to another address which it could find. Seems like I've got some work ahead of me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's strange because it work's on my live demo check this

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/sVKTF/)

Do you have more code somewhere??

**Update**

I test the service with the plus symbol, and even without canada and still worked

[here's examples](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/sVKTF/1/)

Comment: That's very odd. Do you think the + signs and commas have anything to do with it? I'm also not passing the country, although that didn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: I don't think so, because in the documentation say's that the service resolve the problems of the symbols, let me try the service with the plus symbol to see if I'm getting troubles

Comment: I do have more code, but none which has to do with the geocoder. You can see the address I'm generating from the screenshot.

Comment: are you sure that the error of the service its not found and not query `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` , `REQUEST_DENIED`

Comment: That did occur to me, but as you can see my code returns the status directly...which is ZERO_RESULTS.

Comment: I think I may have realized what's going on - I'm looping through three different addresses - since the geocoding is being done asynchronously the address it can't find is not actually the one that's being alerted! I will investigate more and let you know...